# How do I efficiently count a list of intervals against a list of points?

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, time-complexity

So I have a list of intervals, let's say on a real line,

```
let intervals = [(1, 12), (2, 5), (3, 24), (7, 8)]
```

Note that the I use parentheses only because I store them as pairs, the intervals are actually inclusive (closed).

And I have a list of points,

```
let points = [13, 2, 7, 3, 14]
```

I am trying to count the number of points that fall into each interval, this should be an `[Integer]` that has length `length intervals`,

```
counts == [3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Now the problem is in reality both `intervals` and `points` are *really* long, so using a iterative algorithm that takes `O(length intervals * length points)` would take forever. Thus I'm consider using some kind of segment tree to make it `O(log (length intervals) * length points)`. Currently I'm looking at the package [SegmentTree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SegmentTree-0.3). However, my limited Haskell knowledge wasn't enough for me to come up with a complete solution.

I understand that if the objective were to count the number of intervals that cover each point then then solution is straight forward:

```
import qualified Data.SegmentTree as S
map (S.countingQuery $ S.fromList intervals) points
```

But I can't think of a way to do the reverse. To me it seems that in order to do it efficiently a mutable data structure has to be used, and that is just going to open a Pandora Box.

What could be a solution?

Comment: If you can sort the points list first, you can do it pretty quickly: for each interval, find the index in the points list of its lower bound and of its upper bound, and subtract. This comes out to something like `O(log(nPoints) * max(nPoints, nRanges))`, which is a bit better. Linear time is hard to imagine, but maybe I'm missing a clever solution.

Comment: I guess research towards efficient collision detection algorithms would be relevant here. But you should state what you actually know about the distribution of your points and intervals: if the endpoints are uniformly distributed over some interval of the reals then we can say something about the probability of overlapping intervals. Conversely if we say they are randomly distributed over the real line, then... I guess that's either ill-posed, or we get a probability of overlap of 0.

Comment: Consider that we can write a trivial algorithm that runs in linear time when all the intervals overlap precisely.

Comment: If there are many more points than intervals then the natural approach is (1) convert the intervals to half-open ones (2) take all the new endpoints of and sort them (3) cover the line with half-open intervals with these endpoints (4) compute a histogram of how the points fall into these new intervals (5) take partial sums to obtain counts of points in intervals from -infinity and (6) subtract two such sums for each original interval. This is O(log intervals * (intervals + points)). Maybe a fancier segment tree data structure can do better, but I think only in constant factors.

Comment: Oh and maybe you'd like to consider a probabilistic algorithm :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can sort the points list first, you can do it pretty quickly: for each interval, find the index in the points list of its lower bound and of its upper bound, and subtract. Those lookups take log(nPoints) time, and you are doing nRanges of them, so the overall performance will be governed either by the initial sort (n log n) or by the lookups (m log n).

This comes out to `O(log(nPoints) * max(nPoints, nRanges))`, which is certainly better than quadratic time. It's as good as I'd expect to be able to get, too: I don't see any clever way to get down to linear time, and a log factor is pretty small.

The main drawback is that it requires having the entire points list in memory at once, for the sort, whereas you can imagine that a lazy solution could exist that would use less space.

Comment: Is there a pre-defined binary search function in Haskell or do I have to implement it? Also binary search requires random access, does that mean I need to switch to `Vector`?

Comment: The only one I can find is `Data.Vector.Algorithms.Search.binarySearch`, which operates on `MVector`.

Comment: You don't *need* random access to use binary search here, you could just build a balanced binary search tree after sorting the list of points. The constant factor would be better with an array though.

Comment: I think you could use an `IntMap` to map points to their index and then use `lookupLE` or `lookupGE` for the lookup.

Comment: I suppose you could do slightly better -- O(m log m + n) -- using linear-time sorting: include both points and interval endpoints in the list of things you sort in O(m+n) time, then use one pass on the result to produce a map from interval endpoints to point indices in O(m+n) time, then do the lookups you suggested in O(m log m) time. I wonder if it's possible to get rid of that final log m somehow...?

Comment: @trVoldemort: The `vector-algorithms` library comes with a [`binarySearch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Search.html) operation, as well as various sorting algorithms. This requires using the [`vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) library, which may be a good choice anyway if you're really concerned about performance. It will also require using the `ST` or `IO` type.